# C# bind whole appSettings file to class

Tags: c#, configuration, binding, appsettings

In C# we can bind some settings in appSettings to class, for example like that:

```
var connectionStrings = new ConnectionStrings();
var sectionConnectionString = Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings");
```

In appsettings it looks like below:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
```

And when I want to bind Logging I need to call another bind:

```
Configuration.GetSection("Logging");
```

How can I bind whole appsettings file? `GetSection` with empty string doesn't work:

```
Configuration.GetSection("");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a Class for your config and afterwards you can use this (You do not need to map every setting, just the ones you need):

```cs
var configObject = Configuration.Get<ConfigObject>();
```

Example config object:

```cs
public class ConfigObject {
    public Logging Logging { get; set; } 
    public string AllowedHosts { get; set; } 
    public ConnectionStrings ConnectionStrings { get; set; } 
}

public class Logging {
    public LogLevel LogLevel { get; set; } 
}

public class LogLevel {
    public string Default { get; set; } 
}

public class ConnectionStrings {
    public string ConnString1 { get; set; } 
}
```

**Hint:**
if you're not using aspnetcore you probably need to also include this NuGet package: [`Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Configuration instance as it is.

You can bind the settings to a class:

```
var appSettings = Configuration.Get<AppSettings>();
```

Or you can inject the settings with the Options pattern

```
services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration);
```